# Azure ML operations : workspace authentication error

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I need to connect with Azure ML Workspace during deployment over container instance.

```
ws = Workspace(subscription_id="your-sub-id",
              resource_group="your-resource-group-id",
              workspace_name="your-workspace-name"
              )
```

Interactive Authentication to the ML Workspace prompts to login and then fails with below error message.

```
AttributeError: 'BasicTokenAuthentication' object has no attribute 'get_token'
```

[i have been following this Azure Authentication document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-setup-authentication#interactive-authentication)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what version of the SDK are you on?

Comment: @AndersSwanson       Azure ML SDK Version:  1.0.69

Comment: STRONGLY recommend that you upgrade to the latest version of the SDK (`1.1.14`). `1.0.69` was released almost a year ago, and a great deal of things have changed and improved since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this was fixed by updating azureml-core from 1.13.0 to 1.14.0.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an automated deployment, I recommend that you look into using `ServicePrincipalAuthentication` like the doc page that you link suggeests. In this manner, you can pass the client id and client secrets as environment variablse.